# C90 compiler complaining with a No prototype function warning

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-warnings

I have a function `hello()` declared in the file includes.h

The `hello()` function is defined in the file source.c

The `hello()` function gets called in main.c file

**includes.h** contains below code

```
    /*
     * includes.h
     *
     *  Created on: Jul 26, 2018
     *      Author: salim
     */
    #ifndef T_HEADER_H_
    #define T_HEADER_H_

    #include <stdio.h>
    int hello();


    #endif /* T_HEADER_H_ */
```

**source.c** contains below code

```
    /*
     * source.c
     *
     *  Created on: Jul 26, 2018
     *      Author: salim
     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "includes.h"
    int hello()
    {
       printf("Hello, World!");
       return 0;
    }
```

**main.c** contains below code

```
    /*
     * main.c
     *
     *  Created on: Jul 26, 2018
     *      Author: salim
     */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "includes.h"
    int main()
    {
       hello();
       return 0;
    }
```

Compilation passes, but the compiler produces a info message saying `main.c(11) : C0200 (I) No prototype function`

What am i missing to get rid of the info/warning message ? I know that a work around could be to turn of showing warning/info messages but i do not wan't to go that route.

Comment: Looks OK to me. What OS and compiler are you using, and what are you typing on the command line to compile these files?

Comment: You should define and declare `int hello(void)`. For historical reasons (K&R days) no parameters declared means 'parameters undefined' and compilers often produce warnings in that case because they can't check the parameters in calls to the function

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I am on ubuntu 16.04 compiling with Hitachi C/C++ compiler , thanks anyway. as  pointed out in the accepted answer it was an issue with K&R declaration of functions , i had to explicitly specify void as function parameter hello(void)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally it is a "no prototype function" at the point of the call. `int hello()` is not a prototype. It is a function declaration of "non-prototype" kind. It is a K&R-style declaration.

Prototype declaration for this function would look as

```
int hello(void);
```

Whether this is what the compiler was trying to tell you (or there is some other problem) is a different question.

Comment: the info message still appears with built in C functions, i.e. exit(3) with proper header included (#include <stdio.h>) , is there a solution to this situation as well ?

Comment: @salimsaid Might not be the reason, but proper header for `exit` is `<stdlib.h>`, not `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: sorry i had i wrong, i actually included <stdlib.h> not <stdio.h> , should have silenced the warning if that was the case.